# Aligning Image to Same Margin as Text Aligned Right

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, themes

How would you align text (a list) to the right and have an image above it also aligned to the right, but have them both have fixed and 10% away from the left side of the screen. I also want both elements to be fixed. I have a codepen if anyone wants a link to it, but it's super simple and does not have the effect I want. I basically just want this as my "header" and then have the body of the site on the right side of it. For example:

```
        ########             body------->
        #      #
        #      #             body------->
        #      #
        ########             body------->


                             body------->


          Item 1             body------->
          Item 2
   Item Number 3
         Item #4             body------->
```

Comment: Here is a link to my working [link] (http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/mEGzYv) codepen, however I cannot get the text to be aligned near the bottom no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okahara/gcedccgx/) you can look at.

HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item Number 3</li>
    <li>Item #4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="body">
  BODY
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header,
#body {
  display: inline-block;
}

#header {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

#header img,
#header ul {
  padding-right: 10%;
}

ul  {
    list-style: none;
}

#body {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
```

The widths of your header and body can change to what ever you wish. Let me know if you want anything else done.

You can also change the `padding-right: 10%;` to a `margin-right: 10%` depending on what CSS you are applying.

Comment: Wow, that is brilliant! What if I wanted the list to be at bottom: 4%; ?

Comment: I set a random height of 450px and added some more html [here](https://jsfiddle.net/okahara/gcedccgx/3/)

Comment: I apologize. My css should be in alpha order.

Comment: Yeah, that works but is there a way to do it with percentage? Or have it always be a certain height above the bottom of the users screen?

Comment: Right now the list's position from the bottom is using a percentage (4%). If you want to do it based on the user's screen size you would have to update it using javascript or media queries because each user's screen height may be different.

Comment: This is close to what I want http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/JKaQOm and yeah that sounds good, I plan use media queries later in development.